# Divide a MongoDB document into multiple documents based on Date Field using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I have a document on MongoDB that contains flight data records. This data goes back 4 years , and is mixed up in the `flight_records` array shown in the sample below. I want to split this document into separate documents based on the Year of the record. My Sample Document is as follows -

```
{
"flight_number": "AS6312",
"airlines_code": "AS",
"flight_records": [{
        "status": "Landed 13:35",
        "origin": "ONT",
        "destination": "SEA",
        "date_of_journey": "2023-12-21",
        "scheduled": {
            "dep": 1671648300,
            "arr": 1671658500
        },
        "real": {
            "dep": 1671649420,
            "arr": 1671658520
        }
    },
    {
        "status": "Canceled",
        "origin": "ONT",
        "destination": "SEA",
        "date_of_journey": "2022-12-20",
        "scheduled": {
            "dep": 1671561900,
            "arr": 1671572100
        },
        "real": {
            "dep": 0,
            "arr": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "status": "Landed 13:09",
        "origin": "ONT",
        "destination": "SEA",
        "date_of_journey": "2021-12-19",
        "scheduled": {
            "dep": 1671475500,
            "arr": 1671485700
        },
        "real": {
            "dep": 1671475903,
            "arr": 1671484184
        }
    }
]
```

}

And the expected output is three documents, each for 2021-2023.
The Expected output Document 1 ->

```
{
"flight_number": "AS6312",
"airlines_code": "AS",
"flight_records": [
  {
    "status": "Landed 13:35",
    "origin": "ONT",
    "destination": "SEA",
    "date_of_journey": "2023-12-21",
    "scheduled": {
      "dep": 1671648300,
      "arr": 1671658500
    },
    "real": {
      "dep": 1671649420,
      "arr": 1671658520
    }
  }]
```

}

Similarly , Expected output Document 2-> and so on...

```
{
"flight_number": "AS6312",
"airlines_code": "AS",
"flight_records": [
  {
    "status": "Canceled",
    "origin": "ONT",
    "destination": "SEA",
    "date_of_journey": "2022-12-20",
    "scheduled": {
      "dep": 1671561900,
      "arr": 1671572100
    },
    "real": {
      "dep": 0,
      "arr": 0
    }
  }]}
```

Each of these documents will be saved into separate collections later based on the year of the record. I tried using the $match and the $find but couldn't get the correct output.

Comment: Will the stage `{"$unwind": "$flight_records"}` get you close to what you want?

Comment: Actually, unwind will simply return the array as individual elements, but I am confused about the date comparison and how to split the document later, to create separate documents based on year/date.

Comment: After `"$unwind"`, you could use `"$group"` with an appropriate `"_id"` to assemble the documents by year.

Comment: I am new to MongoDB, I understand that I need to somehow appropriately group these by date, but I am not able to understand how.

Comment: This is what I have tried :
` db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$flight_records",
  "$group": {
    "_id": "flight_records",
    "date_of_journey": {
      "year": {
        "$year": new Date("$flight_records.date_of_journey")
      }
    }
  }
})`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that I improvised, I hope others will find it useful.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{
"$unwind": "$flight_records"}, 
{
"$group": {
    _id: {
        $year: {
            $toDate: "$flight_records.date_of_journey"
        }
    },
    recordsForYear: {
        $push: "$flight_records"
    }
}})
```

And here is the result :

```
{
"_id": 2021,
"recordsForYear": [
  {
    "date_of_journey": "2021-11-18",
    "destination": "DTW",
    "origin": "DCA",
    "real": {
      "arr": 1.668740944e+09,
      "dep": 1.668736446e+09
    },
    "scheduled": {
      "arr": 1.66874124e+09,
      "dep": 1.66873524e+09
    },
    "status": "Landed 22:09"
  },
  {
    "date_of_journey": "2021-11-16",
    "destination": "DCA",
    "origin": "DTW",
    "real": {
      "arr": 1.668644421e+09,
      "dep": 1.668640813e+09
    },
    "scheduled": {
      "arr": 1.66864524e+09,
      "dep": 1.6686396e+09
    },
    "status": "Landed 19:20"
  },
  {
    "date_of_journey": "2021-11-14",
    "destination": "DCA",
    "origin": "DTW",
    "real": {
      "arr": 1.668471887e+09,
      "dep": 1.66846811e+09
    },
    "scheduled": {
      "arr": 1.66847244e+09,
      "dep": 1.6684668e+09
    },
    "status": "Landed 19:24"
  }
]},{
"_id": 2023,
"recordsForYear": [
  {
    "date_of_journey": "2023-11-17",
    "destination": "DTW",
    "origin": "DCA",
    "real": {
      "arr": 1.668653594e+09,
      "dep": 1.668649558e+09
    },
    "scheduled": {
      "arr": 1.66865484e+09,
      "dep": 1.66864884e+09
    },
    "status": "Landed 21:53"
  },
  {
    "date_of_journey": "2023-11-15",
    "destination": "DCA",
    "origin": "DTW",
    "real": {
      "arr": 1.668557859e+09,
      "dep": 1.668553656e+09
    },
    "scheduled": {
      "arr": 1.66855884e+09,
      "dep": 1.6685532e+09
    },
    "status": "Landed 19:17"
  },
  {
    "date_of_journey": "2023-11-14",
    "destination": "DTW",
    "origin": "DCA",
    "real": {
      "arr": 1.668395275e+09,
      "dep": 1.668391115e+09
    },
    "scheduled": {
      "arr": 1.66839564e+09,
      "dep": 1.66838964e+09
    },
    "status": "Landed 22:07"
  }
]},{
"_id": 2022,
"recordsForYear": [
  {
    "date_of_journey": "2022-11-17",
    "destination": "DCA",
    "origin": "DTW",
    "real": {
      "arr": 1.668730907e+09,
      "dep": 1.668727074e+09
    },
    "scheduled": {
      "arr": 1.66873164e+09,
      "dep": 1.668726e+09
    },
    "status": "Landed 19:21"
  },
  {
    "date_of_journey": "2022-11-16",
    "destination": "DTW",
    "origin": "DCA",
    "real": {
      "arr": 1.668568424e+09,
      "dep": 1.668564614e+09
    },
    "scheduled": {
      "arr": 1.66856844e+09,
      "dep": 1.66856244e+09
    },
    "status": "Landed 22:13"
  },
  {
    "date_of_journey": "2022-11-15",
    "destination": "DTW",
    "origin": "DCA",
    "real": {
      "arr": 1.668481169e+09,
      "dep": 1.668477413e+09
    },
    "scheduled": {
      "arr": 1.66848204e+09,
      "dep": 1.66847604e+09
    },
    "status": "Landed 21:59"
  }
]
```

}
]